# PHP Tools extension and HTML intellisense

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, editor, intellisense

I got the PHP Tools professional version, but realized that it only has php intellisense, and that it only has color highlighting for HTML.  While html itself admittedly isn't difficult, I would like to have intellisense for it as well.

Does anyone know of a way that I can link both PHP and HTML intellisense to a single extension?

I tried to go to options->Text Editor->File Extension and set the php extension to the HTML editor, but it removed the PHP Tools intellisense and just replaced it with the HTML one.  What I'd really like is to keep the php while adding (not replacing) html editor tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known limitation of external editors for Visual Studio. Anyway according to [PHP Tools features page](http://www.devsense.com/products/php-tools/features) (just updated), the work is in progress. For now, it isn't possible to 'mix' two languages like HTML & PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this thread:

http://support.devsense.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=987

Seems to come soon :-).

Comment: Seems like *soon* is a rather relative term.